# Raster package error

Tags: r, raster

I am using the package `raster`, but get an error with the arguments when trying to use the function `getData()`.  I am using examples directly from the documentation.  For example:

```
require(raster)
getData("GADM", country = 'FRA', level =1)
Error in getData("GADM", country = "FRA", level = 1) : 
  unused arguments (country = "FRA", level = 1)
getData('ISO3')
Error in UseMethod("getData") : 
  no applicable method for 'getData' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a function called `GetData` in the `nlme` package. If you use that version of GetData,  you will get this error message.  Instead,  please try

```
raster::getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)
```